# OnPreRender method does not change control state during postback

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a MasterPage "EditMaster" with a UserControl "CtrlStatus". CtrlStatus simply checks if a specific value is set in a Session. If it is, then it shows it's content, else it stays hidden.

Next I have a Page which prepares table with values and several Buttons in the code-behind (dynamically), based on a variable I pass when accessing the Page. Each Button gets it's Command/OnClick (tried it with both) event linked to a handler.

After the postback, in the handler I save the needed value in the Session. Which should ensure that the content of CtrlStatus will be shown and in the best case scenario, it should be visible on the result of the postback already -> that's why I check the Session value (CtrlStatus) in "OnPreRender" overriden method.

But I can't seem to get the content to show on the result of the postback. The content is shown only after refresh/redirect.

CtrlStatus does NOT have any updatePanel, which to my knowledge might be the underlying problem. But even if it had, I don't know how to call update() on it from the OnClick handler. And if I debug the whole process, the condition in CtrlStatus is evaluated correctly and visibility is set to true.

How do I force the UserControl to display it's content ?

1/ Handler for the dynamically generated control (in Page)

```
private void handleGeneratedBtn(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            LinkButton btn = (LinkButton)sender;
            if (btn.CommandName == "UserID")
            {
                Guid userId;
                if (Guid.TryParse(btn.CommandArgument, out userId))
                {
                    setSessionVariable(userId);
                    updatePanel1.Update();
                }
            }
        }
```

2/ Generation of the Button (in Page)

```
            int counter = 0;
            foreach (var userID in listUsers)
            {
                TableRow row = new TableRow();

                LinkButton b = new LinkButton();
                b.ID = "Btn_User_" + counter++;
                b.CommandArgument = userID ;
                b.CommandName = "UserID";
                b.Command += handleGeneratedBtn;
                TableCell c = new TableCell();
                c.Controls.Add(b);
                row.Cells.Add(c);
                rows.Add(row);
            }
```

3/ OnPreRedner method of the CtrlStatus (UserControl that exists in MasterPage)

```
protected override void OnPreRender(EventArgs e)
    {
        var value = getSessionVariable();

        if (value != null)
        {
            if (value == "something")
            {
                showContent();
            }
            else
            {
                hideContent();
            }
        }
        base.OnPreRender(e);
    }
```

Comment: Difficult to comment without code - but it sounds like you might have a lifecycle problem that you're trying to access PreRender in the wrong control at the wrong time - because I noticed you mention "dynamically" which usually is what trips people. But for help on how to solve it, would require actual code shown and/or you could make a small proof-of-concept attempt and see if it works there.

Comment: Thanks for the comment I added excerpt of the code, hope it sheds some more light on the problem. Also I would like to add, that even thou the Buttons are dynamically generated, the handler still catches the event since the Buttons are also generated on the post-back.

Comment: Can you please confirm you've debugged this issue and can see the OnPreRender method being hit?

Comment: Yes I can confirm that the event fires as it should. Handler sets the variable to Session. OnPreRender method is hit and correctly evaluates the condition based on the Session variable (therefore setting content of control to visible). Everything seems like it's working as it should, it's just that the content of the Control is not visible once the page is rendered/displayed in browser.

Comment: Super late, but I had a similar issue recently and I came across this article.  I had my issue because I was using ````Me.Visible = False```` (this was VB.net, I guess it would be base.Visible in C#) and therefore the control was not able to be accessed on PostBacks.